VirtualBox Ubuntu: "failed to read dockerfile open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit... no such file or directory"
I have the simplest hello world Java application. Its filesystem:
|-- HelloWorld
   |-- src
      |-- Main.java
   |-- Dockerfile

I use VirtualBox 7.0 with Ubuntu x64 and Docker 24.0.5.
When I try to build the application image from that Dockerfile using this command:
docker build -t hello .

I get this error:
root@ubuntu: /media/sf_IdeaProjects/HelloWorld# docker build -t hello.
[+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
=> [internal] load .dockerignore
=> => transferring dockerfile: 2B
=> => transferring context: 2B
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1689060805/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

The "IdeaProjects" folder is shared with the VirtualBox guest OS.
Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src .
RUN javac Main.java 
CMD ["java", "Main"]

Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}


Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

@g00se I understand. Sorry. I can't (don't know) copy-paste from VirtualBox Ubuntu. But I made a correspondent title to be searchable

Well, you certainly need to learn to copy-paste from your terminal

Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].  In addition to @g00se's request to include the error message in plain text, it'd also help to see the Dockerfile and the exact command you're using to build the image.

@DavidMaze I updated my question. Hope this helps.

(1)Your file Main.java, Dockerfile, and docker build command are all correct, and can be executed normally in my test VM (VirtualBox) . (2)My test VM (Ubuntu 20.04), under normal users Account (Ex: demouser), execute sudo apt install docker.io (3)Test the Docker command: sudo docker run hello-world can work  (4)  sudo su-, cd /media/sf_IdeaProjects/HelloWorld, Then test that your docker build -t hello . can operate normally. Everything can operate normally and your error message will not appear. (5)It can be assumed that it is a problem with your environment config or setting.

(1) My habit is to copy the files in the shared folder to my local machine and then operate the files.
(2) (Suppose I am now the default user demouser logging into VM Ubuntu)
(3) cd ~/Downloads , sudo cp -R  /media/sf_IdeaProjects/HelloWorld ./,
sudo chown -R demouser:demouser HelloWorld,
cd ~/Downloads/HelloWorld, docker build -t hello .

@life888888 I copied the files from the shared folder to the local Ubuntu folder and it worked. Why doesn't this work for shared folders in a virtual machine? I will be bored to copy after single change.

(A) Execute directly in Share Folder or (B) Copy from Share Folder to Guest OS Local such as ~/Downloads. I have tested both scenarios. On my VM, it can be executed normally. (C ) The only thing I don’t know is how you installed and set up Docker. In addition, in Ubuntu, I always use the default user account, and then sudo to execute commands without switching to the root account. (This is also what I use in Ubuntu. Ubuntu usage habits)

(D) Because the file permissions in Share Folder are given to root by default (for Guest OS), so I usually copy the directory or file from Share Folder first, and then change the Ownert to the current user. Then operate the file. As for why you can't work normally, I judged that in my environment, both scenario tests can work successfully.

It is also worth mentioning that when I directly accessed the Share Folder file in the Guest to perform operations, at the same time, I did not use IDEA or other IDE to open the HelloWolrd directory in the Host. Have you used IDEA to open the project directory in the Host? Then perform Docker operations in the Guest and directly in the Share Folder?

@life888888 I didn't manually install Docker. When I was installing Ubuntu it recommended me a list of often downloadable programs and I choosed Docker. I run the docker build command in the shared folder from the root of the project where Dockerfile is.
